# std::pair<auto, auto> return type

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, auto, std-pair

I was playing around with `auto` in `std::pair`. In the below code, function `f` is supposed to return a `std::pair` of types which depend on a template parameter.

A working example:

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
template <unsigned S>
auto f()
{
    if constexpr (S == 1)
        return std::pair{1, 2}; // pair of ints
    else if constexpr (S == 2)
        return std::pair{1.0, 2.0}; // pair of doubles
    else
        return std::pair{0.0f, 0.0f}; // pair of floats
}
```

This works with gcc 9.2, gcc 10.0, clang 9.0 and clang 10.0.

Next, I wanted to explicitly write the return type as a `std::pair` for clarity reasons:

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
template <unsigned S>
std::pair<auto, auto> f()
{
    if constexpr (S == 1)
        return {1, 2};
    /* ... */
}
```

Both gcc 9.2/10.0 and clang 9.0/10.0 failed to compile this.

***gcc 9.2***

```
error: invalid use of 'auto'
error: template argument 1 is invalid // first argument (auto) of std::pair
error: template argument 2 is invalid // second argument (auto) of std::pair
error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'int' in return
```

From the last error message, gcc 9.2 seems to believe that `std::pair<auto, auto>` is an `int`. How can this be explained?

***gcc 10.0***

```
error: returning initializer list
```

This error is understandable, however, I expected the constructor of `std::pair` to be invoked, or is there something I am missing here?

***clang 9.0 and 10.0***

```
'auto' not allowed in template argument
excess elements in scalar initializer
no matching function for call to 'f'
```

Ok, clang doesn't like any of this. From the second error message, it seems that clang also believes the return type is `int`.

Finally, to fix the error obtained compiling with gcc 10.0, I decided to return a `std::pair` explicitly:

**EXAMPLE 3**

```
template <unsigned S>
std::pair<auto, auto> f()
{
    if constexpr (S == 1)
        return std::pair{1, 2};
    /* ... */
}
```

***clang 9.0 and 10.0***

Same as before, but with an additional:

```
no viable conversion from returned value of type 'std::pair<int, int>' to function return type 'int'
```

Here clang still thinks we are returning an `int`?

***gcc 9.2***

Same as before.

***gcc 10.0***

It works!

I guess some features still have to be implemented, or in one of the situations described above, is there a compiler which is right and the other wrong? In my opinion, example 2 should work. Or should it not?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The syntax:

```
std::pair<auto, auto> f() { return std::pair(1, 2); }
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Was part of the original Concepts TS but was not included in the Concepts proposal that is part of C++20. As such, the only placeholder types in C++20 are `auto` (and variations thereof like `auto**`), `decltype(auto)`, and constrained placeholders (`Concept auto` and variations thereof). This kind of nested placeholder type would be very useful, but is not part of C++20, so that function declaration is ill-formed.

Now, gcc allows it because gcc implemented the Concepts TS and I guess they decided to keep this feature. clang never implemented the TS, so it doesn't.

Either way, this:

```
std::pair<auto, auto> f() { return {1, 2}; }
```

Would always be ill-formed. The meaning of the syntax is that we deduce the return type and then require that it matches `pair<T, U>` for some types `T` and `U`. We're basically trying to invoke the invented function:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void __f(std::pair<T, U>);

__f({1, 2}); // this must succeed
```

But you cannot deduce a type from `{1, 2}` - a braced-init-list doesn't have a type. Perhaps this is something that should be explored (as it's easy to understand at least in a simple case like this), but it has never been allowed. So rejecting it is correct either way.

Lastly:

> gcc 9.2 seems to believe that `std::pair<auto, auto>` is an `int`. How can this be explained?

For some reason (probably due to our C legacy with implicit `int`), when gcc does not recognize or understand a type, it just uses `int` as the placeholder in error messages. This is super confusing, because obviously it's gcc that came up with `int` and not the source code. But that's the way it is.

Comment: The "braced-init-list doesn't have a type argument" is not clear to me. std::pair<int, int> f() { return {1,2}; } does work, and {1,2} has no type (it invokes the constructor of std::pair<int,int> as I understand it). Maybe with <auto, auto>, the compiler can't deduce the types of 1, and 2 in the initializer list {1, 2} ?

Comment: @mfnx Not doesn't have a type _argument_, just doesn't have a type. braced init lists can only be used in certain situations - like initializing a known type. But they cannot be used in deduction - because they have no type. Except `auto x = {1, 2};` works, but only if all the types are the same.

Comment: I meant: that argument is not clear to me (I should have closed the "" before the word argument).

Comment: Most compilers, instead of just stopping at the first error, try to recover from it so they can report additional errors. This generally means assuming that everything unparseable is an `int`. It's not that `int` is a placeholder in error messages; the compiler really thinks that it's an `int`. (To make this clearer, gcc should probably have said "assuming int" at some point.)

Comment: Note that another possible avenue for extension would be to allow class template argument deduction for return types, since `std::pair __f{1,2};` works.

Comment: @DavisHerring I would not really want to have `std::optional f() { return 4; }` work.

Comment: *"Was part of the original Concepts TS but was not included in the Concepts proposal that is part of C++20."* Do you happen to know why this was dropped? And, is there any chance this feature might come back in future versions of C++?